# How to strach div in some line to "all left space" with css

Tags: css, xhtml

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .panel
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
                background: #f2f2f2;
            }

            #after-top
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 90px;
                left: 1px;
                right: 1px;
                font-size: 16px;
            }

            #languages
            {
                width: 120px;
                text-align: center;
                float: left;
            }

            #location
            {
                float: left;
                margin: 0 1px 0 1px;  
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="after-top">
            <span class="panel" id="languages"><span>English</span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<span>Русский</span></span>
            <span class="panel" id="location">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This produce some thing like:

```
+-------------------+ +-+
| English | Russian | | |
+-------------------+ +-+
```

I want second div stretched till end of screen minus 1px.
Some thing like:

```
+-------------------+ +--------------------------------------------------------+
| English | Russian | |                                                        |
+-------------------+ +--------------------------------------------------------+
```

And when I wil upzoom the screen I don't want effects like:

```
+-------------------+
| English | Russian |
+-------------------+
            +-----------------------------------------------------------+
            |                                                           |
            +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

But (when I will upgrade zoom of window) something like:

```
+-------------------+ +------------------------------+
| English | Russian | |                              |
+-------------------+ +------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `overflow:hidden`:

```
#panel {
    display: block;
}
#after-top, #location {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#languages {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS3 flexible boxes, but it wouldn't work in all browsers (IE, we're looking at you).

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one">One</div>
    <div id="two">Two</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    background: rgb(230,230,230);
    display: -moz-box; -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    padding: 15px;
}
#container #one {
    background: rgb(200,200,200);
    padding: 15px;
}
#container #two {
    -moz-box-flex: 1; -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    background: rgb(200,200,200);
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DAsrx/

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use DIVs instead of SPANs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .panel {
                border: 1px solid black;
                background: #f2f2f2;
            }
            #after-top {
                position: absolute;
                top: 90px;
                left: 1px;
                right: 1px;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            #languages {
                width: 120px;
                text-align: center;
                float: left;
                background: green;
            }
            #location {
                background: red;
                margin: 0 0 0 122px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="after-top">
            <div class="panel" id="languages"><span>English</span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<span>Русский</span></div>
            <div class="panel" id="location"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```